# ParallelTable does not execute in parallel

Tags: parallelization, kernel

I would like to construct a Table in Parallel in Mathematica. However, it only uses one Kernel for the calculation, the others run idle. My code looks like this (I will remove a big chunk of the formula for `f2` to remove cluttering the code section of the question):

```
mval = 1
bval = 1
nv = 150

getnu[l_] := ((2*l+1)*Pi)/bval;

f1[nu_, nup_ ,m_, b_]:= b/(I*(nu+nup)-m) + ...;
f2[nu_, nup_] := N[f1[nu, nup, mval, bval], 30];

LaunchKernels[];
DistributeDefinitions[getnu, f2];
result = ParallelTable[f2[getnu[i-nv], getnu[j-nv]], {i, 0, 2*nv-1}, {j, 0, 2*nv-1}];
```

Ultimately, I want to fill the Matrix with the function `f2` evaluated at values that depend on the current Matrix row and column. I do not see an immediate issue as to why this does not work. I tried specifying the functions in a specific context (and with `DistributedContexts->Automatic`), but that also did not help. Also, including `nv` in `DistributeDefinitions` does not affect the execution. I am using version 13.3.1. Edit: Formula for f1 is a combination of Eq. (B11) and Eq. (B12) from [this paper here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/9905242.pdf).

Comment: `{i, 0, 2*nv-1}, {j, 0, 2*nv-1}` is only 400 elements, which for a very quick function like `f2` is hardly anything. Just using a `Table` is faster because of the overheads associated with `LaunchKernels` and `ParallelTable`.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I should include this here then: My code up there is a small version of what I am actually using. There, nv is of order 100-150, the real function f2 is a lot longer than what I posted, and it also includes a Series expansion. My idea was to post a minimal working example to not clutter the code section of the question too much.